# UART resource temporarily unavaiable before running minicom

Tags: c, serial-port, uart

I'm having an issue with UART on linux. Here is my program:

```html
void open_IMU_UART_connection() {
 /* Description:
  * This function opens the UART communication channel for the Razor IMU
  */
 printf("Opening Razor IMU UART connection... ");
 write_to_file_custom(everything_log,"Opening Razor IMU UART connection... ",error_log);
 if ((RAZOR_UART=open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY))<0) {
  sprintf(ERROR_MESSAGE,"CRITICAL ERROR: Failed to open the Razor IMU connection on /dev/ttyUSB0");
  write_to_file_custom(everything_log,ERROR_MESSAGE,error_log);
  perror(ERROR_MESSAGE); fflush(stdout);
  exit(-2); // Exit with a critical failure
 }
 printf("opened.\n"); fflush(stdout);
}

void UART_config() {
 /* Description:
  * This function sets up UART connection properties for the Razor IMU UART connection
  */
 printf("Setting up Razor IMU UART connection properties... ");
 write_to_file_custom(everything_log,"Setting up Razor IMU UART connection properties... ",error_log);
 tcgetattr(RAZOR_UART,&UART_options);
 UART_options.c_cflag = B57600 | CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL;
 UART_options.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
 tcflush(RAZOR_UART, TCIFLUSH);
 tcsetattr(RAZOR_UART,TCSANOW,&UART_options);
 printf("setup.\nWaiting for 5 seconds... "); fflush(stdout);
 write_to_file_custom(everything_log,"setup.\nWaiting for 5 seconds... ",error_log);
 usleep(5000000); // Sleep 5 seconds to be sure that the IMU UART connection has time to be configured
 printf("finished waiting!\n\nType [Calibrate] to begin calibrating IMU: ");
 write_to_file_custom(everything_log,"finished waiting!\n\nType [Calibrate] to begin calibrating IMU: ",error_log);
 Treat_reply("Calibrate");
}

void UART_IMU_write(FILE *error_log) {
 /* Description:
  * This funtion writes #f to the Razor IMU, which tells the on-board Atmel microcontroller to send back to the Raspberry Pi
  * the current Euler angles (an array of 12 bytes, which has 4 bytes for Pitch, 4 bytes for Yaw, 4 bytes for Roll in IEEE754
  * float representation, backwards)
  */
 if((byte_count=write(RAZOR_UART,IMU_TX,3))<0) { // Send Razor IMU command that "I want to know Euler angles"
  sprintf(ERROR_MESSAGE,"Failed to write to the Razor IMU UART connection.\n");
  write_to_file_custom(everything_log,ERROR_MESSAGE,error_log);
  perror(ERROR_MESSAGE); fflush(stdout);
  write_to_file_custom(error_log,ERROR_MESSAGE,error_log);
  exit(-2); // Exit with a critical failure
 }
}

void UART_IMU_receive(FILE *error_log) {
 /* Descrpition:
  * This function loops until all 12 bytes have been received from the Razor IMU in response to the #f call by (UART_IMU_write)
  * function.
  */
 do {
  if((byte_count=read(RAZOR_UART,IMU_RX,MAX_BUFFER))<0) {
   sprintf(ERROR_MESSAGE,"Failed to read from the Razor IMU UART.\n");
   write_to_file_custom(everything_log,ERROR_MESSAGE,error_log);
   perror(ERROR_MESSAGE); fflush(stdout);
   write_to_file_custom(error_log,ERROR_MESSAGE,error_log);
   exit(-2); // Exit with a critical failure
  } else {
   memcpy(&read_string[ii_start],IMU_RX,byte_count*sizeof(unsigned char));
   ii_start=ii_start+byte_count;

   memset(IMU_RX,0,MAX_BUFFER);
   if (ii_start==12) {
    continue_collecting=0; // All has been read, exit reading loop
    //printf("%d : %s\n",ii_start,read_string);
   }
  }
 } while(continue_collecting);
}

int main() {
     open_IMU_UART_connection();
     UART_config();
     UART_IMU_write(error_log);
  UART_IMU_receive(error_log);
}
```

My problem : when I run the program after connecting the serial device for the first time, I get "Resource temporarily unavailable" error. However when I run "sudo minicom ..." I can communicate with the device; then, when I rerun the program after closing minicom, my program works! What may be the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: Sidenote: you appear to have some documentation already in the code. Evedr thought to do the full step and use doxygen or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar prblem with Ubuntu. The ttyUSBs just lost their peer connection occassionally. After I deactivated the broadband network entry (GSM/UMTS-stick; these emulate a classic modem on a serial port) in the NetworkManager, the problem disappeared. I suspect some of these processes trying to detect a BB-modem automatically and interferes with the normal usage.

As NetworkManager is common with other distributions, too, you might have a look at this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggestion. However this is not an "occassional" problem, but rather that I persistently get "resource temporarily unavailable" when connecting **until** running minicom (sudo minicom -b 57600 -o -D /dev/ttyUSB0), after which the "resource temporarily unavailable" disappears until the next unplug/plug cycle of the serial device.

Comment: I might have been imprecise. By occansionally, I mean it happens from time to time. Although it might not be the same origin, there might as well be another process which takes the interface and creates some kind of race-condition. Perhaps minicom does something more clever to reserve the port. I'll delete the answer if you insist.